# Getting error with aspnet core 2.1 action filter due to missing suitable constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have made a claims filter

```
public class ClaimRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public ClaimRequirementAttribute(string claimType, ClaimRoles claimValue) : base(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] {new Claim(claimType, claimValue.ToString()) };
    }
}

public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var headers = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers;

        var tokenSuccess = headers.TryGetValue("Token", out var token);

        var emailSuccess = headers.TryGetValue("Email", out var email);

        var deviceNameSuccess = headers.TryGetValue("DeviceName", out var deviceName);

        if (tokenSuccess && emailSuccess && deviceNameSuccess)
        {
            var accountLogic = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAccountLogic>();

            var hasClaim = accountLogic.ValidateLogin(email, token, deviceName).Result.Success;

            if (!hasClaim)
            {
                context.HttpContext.ForbidAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.HttpContext.ForbidAsync();
        }
    }
```

}

I have registered the filter in my startup

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<ConnectionStringsSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddScoped<ClaimRequirementFilter>();
```

But I get this error when I navigate to an action that uses the filter

```
[HttpPost]
[ClaimRequirement("Permission", ClaimRoles.Admin)]
public async Task ResetLeaderboard()
```

> InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Foosball.Logic.ClaimRequirementFilter' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor

github: https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball/tree/core2.1/Foosball

Comment: You need to include your code in the body of your question.  External links are not helpful if they break/get deleted.

Comment: @maccettura Done

Comment: Have you looked at using policy based Authorization and making use of the existing `[Authorize]` attribute? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: @Brad Last time it seemed like a big hassle to make any kind of inbuild auth work with Mongodb database and nuget packages doing it for me updated to aspnet core 2.0 and forward are rare. 

So for now I just made some simple security (Might be very unsecure) for this little foosball app, but I might look at it in the future :) but its better than the no security we had before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code has

```
Arguments = new object[] {new Claim(claimType, claimValue.ToString()) };
```

you need to add the following constructor:

```
public ClaimRequirementFilter(Claim claim)
{

}
```

That is because the [internal constructor resolving logic](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/shared/Microsoft.Extensions.ActivatorUtilities.Sources/ActivatorUtilities.cs#L230) uses `TypeFilterAttribute.Argument` property to decide what constructor to use for instantiation.